# SOLVED: There is Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier when defining a variable in code block

Tags: javascript

I have this error when I define a `const` variable in a code block:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

I have already checked if I missed a extra comma, colon, parenthesis, quote or bracket, but still I get the error after I replaced the comma into curly brackets.

```js
const multipleCircles = [{
  calc1: {
    const a = 10;
    area: Math.PI * Math.pow(a, 2);
  },
  calc2: {
    const a = 100;
    area: Math.PI * Math.pow(a, 2);
  }
}];
console.log(multipleCircles);
```

It works when I remove the variables and replace the `a` in `Math.pow` in 10. So what is going wrong with the `const` variables?

SOLVED:
I have mixed up the terms Code Block and Objects Literals. I was focusing into the fundamentals of JavaScript. That's why I got a little confused. Because Objects Literals can only have property definitions and not things like variables. But Code Blocks can use variables. But in this case it wasn't. The code below solved the problem.

```js
const multipleCircles = [{
  calc1:
  {
    radiusBlockSeperate: 10,
    get area() { return Math.PI * Math.pow(this.radiusBlockSeperate, 2)}
  },
  calc2:
  {
    radiusBlockSeperate: 100,
    get area() {return Math.PI * Math.pow(this.radiusBlockSeperate, 2)}
  }
  }];
console.log(multipleCircles);
```

I have added a get(). That is a function getter. Read more about getters [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get). I could solve this problem thanks to @NickParsons.

Comment: The issue is because `calc1` and `calc2` are objects. You cannot have any logic directly within an object; only property definitions. Change `const a = N;` to `a: 10,` and `a: 100,`. This guide may also help: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics#dot_notation)

Comment: That's not a bode block, you cannot assign code blocks as properties

Comment: As others have mentioned, for properties you need `a: 10`. You can then use a getter to refer to the `a` property with `this.a` like: `{a: 10, get area() { return Math.PI * Math.pow(this.a, 2)}`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you for the explanation. I was experimenting with code blocks. And was watching a video about code blocks. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zp7JrqYEapk) is the link of that video. Can you please explain why he was using variables that way?

Comment: That video is absolute garbage. Separating code using `{}` is completely pointless. If you need to separate logic out, or repeat it, use classes/functions to extract the logic to keep the code DRY. Bring back the YT downvote stats.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I thinks that's why I made the mistake. I agree Youtube really need to bring back the dislike button. But thank you for your answer. I'll keep an eye out for that in the future.

Comment: @NickParsons Hi, do you have a MDN page that explains this in detail? Because I want to learn more about this `get()` method.

Comment: @Bennpoes You can read more about getters [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

Comment: @Bennpoes No worries. Also in your previous comment you seem to think that your `{}` here denotes a code-block, which is not the case. `{}` can be mean code block or object literal. In this case, you're creating [object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) by using `{}` and not a code block.

Comment: You can also read [this post](https://gist.github.com/getify/712d994419326b53cabe20138161908b) for some use cases for standalone code blocks (usually they're part of an if-statement or some other JavaScript construct and not standalone).

Comment: @NickParsons Ohh yeah thanks. I was a little confused about it. I have searched in MDN and found that [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block#using_a_block_statement_to_encapsulate_data) was actually what I was working with. So I think I mixed up these two. Can you please check what the difference is here?

Comment: @Bennpoes Yeah, you've mixed up code blocks and object literals. You can read that MDN article you linked and the one I linked above about object literals to see how they differ.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are trying but the closest with the least change to your code is this

```js
const multipleCircles = [{
  calc1: () => {
    const a = 10;
    return Math.PI * Math.pow(a, 2);
  },
  calc2: () => {
    const a = 100;
    return Math.PI * Math.pow(a, 2);
  }
}];
console.log(multipleCircles[0].calc1());
console.log(multipleCircles[0].calc2());
```